# Printing a value if the payment category has no item inside

Tags: php, mysql, sum, payment

I have 4 **payment methods**:

> Cash, Credit, Debit & Paycheck.

What i'm trying to do is print a formated `<td>0</td>` if there's no items results (Previous payments) inside the payment method. The example of the output that im looking for is:

```
Credit   < td >4000< / td >

Cash     < td >0< / td >

Debit    < td >2000< / td >

PayCheck   < td >0< / td >
```

This is my Mysql Query

```
SELECT  SUM(ventas.preciov) as totalp, SUM(boletas.total) as totalb, 
boletas.total, boletas.tpago, boletas.idb, boletas.activa,  ventas.idbv, ventas.marcap
FROM boletas,ventas
WHERE ventas.idbv = boletas.idb AND ventas.marcap = '1' AND boletas.activa = 's'
AND boletas.fventa >= curdate()-INTERVAL '".$_GET["fventa"]."' day GROUP BY tpago 
ORDER BY  tpago DESC
```

This is is my PHP CODE

```
<?php while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $i=$result["tpago"];
    $c= $result["total"];
    switch ($i) {
    case "Cash":
    echo $c;
    break;
    case "Credit":
    echo $c;
    break;  
    case "Debit":
    echo $c;
    break;          
    case "Paycheck":
    echo $c;
    break;    
    } ?>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please convert your table names to meaningful english names and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then this code below may help you:

```
<?php
$payment_methods = array('Credit', 'Cash', 'Debit', 'Paycheck');

$total = array();
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
  $total[$result['tpago']] = $result['total'];

foreach($payment_methods as $method) {
  echo $method.' : '.( empty($total[$method])? 0 : $total[$method] ) . '<br/>';
}
?>
```